# Is there a way to destroy/replace a GameObject that is inside or part of a Prefab instance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwU5s.jpg)

I'm getting exception in the editor:

InvalidOperationException: Destroying a GameObject inside a Prefab instance is not allowed.

Then I have to go manual to open the prefab and remove the gameobject from in there. But is there a way to do it by script automatic ?

This is my script to replace gameobjects with prefab.
The only change I did for the prefab is taking a gmeobject and added to it some colors and texture all the scripts and other stuff are the same.

I'm trying to replace all the doors in the scene with the prefab that is also a door just with some colors and texture.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PrefabReplace : EditorWindow
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;
    private bool selectionChanged;
    private string objectsToSearch = "";
    private List<GameObject> foundObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<GameObject> duplicatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    private bool searched = false;
    private int count = 0;
    private int countChilds = 0;
    private bool countChildren = false;
    private GUIStyle guiStyle = new GUIStyle(); //create a new variable
    private Texture timage;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Prefab Replace")]
    static void CreateReplaceWithPrefab()
    {
        int width = 340;
        int height = 300;

        int x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        int y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<PrefabReplace>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        Texture oo = null;
        Texture texture = (Texture)oo;
        //EditorGUI.DrawTextureTransparent(new Rect(10, 10, 20, 20), timage);

        guiStyle.fontSize = 20; //change the font size
        Searching();
        GUILayout.Space(50);
        Replacing();
    }

    private void Searching()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 20, 150, 20), "Search by name", guiStyle);
        objectsToSearch = GUI.TextField(new Rect(90, 60, 150, 20), objectsToSearch, 25);

        if (objectsToSearch != "")
        {
            GUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }
        GUILayout.Space(40);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Search"))
        {
            foundObjects = new List<GameObject>();
            duplicatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
            countChildren = true;
            countChilds = 0;
            count = 0;

            foreach (GameObject gameObj in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>())
            {
                if (gameObj.name == objectsToSearch)
                {
                    count += 1;
                    foundObjects.Add(gameObj);
                    Transform[] childs = gameObj.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
                    foreach (Transform go in childs)
                    {
                        foundObjects.Add(go.gameObject);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (foundObjects.Count > 0)
            {
                searched = true;
            }
            else
            {
                searched = false;
            }
        }

        GUI.enabled = true;
        if (count > 0)
            GUI.TextField(new Rect(90, 85, 60, 15), count.ToString(), 25);

        if (foundObjects.Count > 0 && countChildren == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < foundObjects.Count; i++)
            {
                if (foundObjects[i].transform.childCount > 0)
                {
                    countChilds += foundObjects[i].transform.childCount;
                }
            }

            countChildren = false;
        }
        GUI.enabled = true;
        if (countChilds > 0)
            GUI.TextField(new Rect(90, 105, 60, 15), countChilds.ToString(), 25);

        GUILayout.Space(100);

        if (foundObjects.Count > 0)
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Test");
    }

    private void Replacing()
    {
        GUILayout.Space(20);
        GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
        GUILayout.Label("Replacing");
        GUILayout.Space(20);

        prefab = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Prefab", prefab, typeof(GameObject), false);

        var selection = Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().ToList();
        if (selectionChanged)
        {
            if (selection.Count == 0)
                GUI.enabled = false;

            for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                var selectedObject = selection[i];
                if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0 &&
                    selectedObject.scene.name != null
                    && prefab != PrefabUtility
                    .GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(selectedObject))
                {
                    GUI.enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    GUI.enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.enabled = false;
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Replace"))
        {
            InstantiatePrefab(selection);
            selectionChanged = false;
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        GUI.enabled = true;
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Selection count: " + Selection.objects.OfType<GameObject>().Count());

        GUILayout.EndVertical();
    }

    private void OnInspectorUpdate()
    {
        Repaint();
    }

    private void OnSelectionChange()
    {
        selectionChanged = true;
    }

    private void InstantiatePrefab(List<GameObject> selection)
    {
        if (prefab != null && selection.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                var selected = selection[i];
                Component[] components = selected.GetComponents(typeof(MonoBehaviour));
                if (components.Length == 0)
                {
                    SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(selected.scene.name));

                    var prefabType = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType(prefab);
                    GameObject newObject;

                    if (prefabType == PrefabType.Prefab)
                    {
                        newObject = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(prefab);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newObject = Instantiate(prefab);
                        newObject.name = prefab.name;
                    }
                    if (newObject == null)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Error instantiating prefab");
                        break;
                    }

                    Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(newObject, "Replace With Prefabs");
                    newObject.transform.parent = selected.transform.parent;
                    newObject.transform.localPosition = selected.transform.localPosition;
                    newObject.transform.localRotation = selected.transform.localRotation;
                    newObject.transform.localScale = selected.transform.localScale;
                    newObject.transform.SetSiblingIndex(selected.transform.GetSiblingIndex());
                    Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(selected);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the doors was replaced fine but the door in the screenshot is the only one that is part of a prefab instance.

Comment: Given the exception being thrown...probably not.

Comment: I found this: if (UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.IsPartOfPrefabInstance(transform))
                            UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance(gameObject, UnityEditor.PrefabUnpackMode.Completely, UnityEditor.InteractionMode.AutomatedAction); but not sure how to use it in my code. Found it a thread in the unity forum.

Comment: That doesn't do what you think it does. What that does is disconnect an instantiated prefab instance from its prefab (so the scene object is no longer a prefab). That did, however, lead me to something that *might* work.

Answer (score 3):

## [PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.LoadPrefabContents.html)

This method does the following:

> Loads a Prefab Asset at a given path into an isolated Scene and returns the root GameObject of the Prefab.
>
> You can use this to get the content of the Prefab **and modify it directly** instead of going through an instance of the Prefab. This is useful for batch operations.

This will let you modify the prefab in the manner you desire, however:

> Once you have modified the Prefab you have to write it back using [`SaveAsPrefabAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset.html) and then call [`UnloadPrefabContents`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.UnloadPrefabContents.html) to release the Prefab and isolated Scene from memory.

You have to save it back to the original prefab again and overwrite your changes.

Comment: I will use your solution. I thought my solution here in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527736/how-can-i-get-a-gameobject-root-prefab/55528112#55528112 Is working fine but it's messing up things. I will try now your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can do this, I solve this. Just destroy all prefab transforms. I have root _Canvas, and Prefab _Panel. And I delete like this:

```
foreach (Transform child in _Canvas.transform)
    GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
```

Childer objects is prefab objects.