# How can I get a GameObject root prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a EditorWindow script.

Inside OnGUI:

```
for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                var selected = selection[i];

                if (UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.IsPartOfPrefabInstance(selected))
                {
                    var root = selected.GetComponentInParent(typeof(GameObject));
                    PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance(selected, PrefabUnpackMode.Completely, UnityEditor.InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);
                }
             }
```

I want to find the prefab the selected is part of.
But this give me exception:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'GameObject' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.

The main goal is destroy a gameobject that is a part of a prefab instance.
For that I need first to find the gameobject(selected) it's prefab the unpack it from the prefab and then to destroy it.

But I can't get the prefab of it.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution:

```
for (var i = selection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                var selected = selection[i];

                if (UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.IsPartOfPrefabInstance(selected))
                {
                    var root = PrefabUtility.GetOutermostPrefabInstanceRoot(selected);
                    PrefabUtility.UnpackPrefabInstance(root, PrefabUnpackMode.Completely, UnityEditor.InteractionMode.AutomatedAction);
                }
            }
```